# How do you make NetBeans ignore files when searching for files?

Tags: netbeans

In NetBeans when you go to Navigate -> Go to File you can search for files by filename. Is there a way to instruct NetBeans to ignore some files. It's picking lots of files from a tmp directory in my project which I never intend to open and it's just noise.

Comment: +1. I would love this feature. It pisses me off having the cache/log directories in my apps searched. Even if they are ignored in subversion, NetBeans searches them. Stupid!

Answer (score 33):

You can also add folders to the "Files ignored by the IDE" configuration.

Select *Tools|Options* and add the folder names to the regex.

[image: Netbeans: Files ignored by IDE]

NB: I have not yet confirmed that this achieves what is described.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me - I needed to exclude the "build" folder from "Go To File..." in an Java Ant project.

Comment: but that these folders won't be visible in project tree at all. Is it possible exclude files with some extension only from search?

Comment: @milkovsky - Each is a regex so try something like `.*\.tmp` to exclude *.tmp* files - I have not tested this.

Comment: Yes. It's clean. E.g. I've added `.*\.test`. But now I can't see `.test` files in Project explorer. Seems now Netbeans ignores `.test` files totaly. I want just exclude them from search, not from IDE. Is it possible?

Comment: @milkovsky - I don't know - sorry. :(

Comment: anyway thank you for the answer. Looks like it's impossible. I share the solution if I'll find it

Comment: In my particular scenario I was able to just temporarily add the exclusion, do my searches, then remove the exclusion.  My searches were a one and done type of thing though.  It could get annoying having to add and remove them constantly.

Comment: I've added to ignore files pattern two lines:
`style.*.css` and `.*.css.map` but I still see style.css and style_desktop.css when searching. Anyone knows what is the problem?

Comment: @MladenAdamovic - Remember that this is all **one** regex - not a file wild-card pattern. Perhaps try something like `...|style.?\.css` like my `...|vssver.?\.scc|..`.

Comment: thanks @OldCurmudgeon I've added to the front of the regex and it seems it works, but btw default regex in my version of netbeans looks incorrect, `^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|git.+|hgignore)$).*$` notice that there are two $ signes in the last part, I think $ there stands for the end of the filename

Answer (score 12):

In NetBeans 7 you go to "Project Properties" then to "Ignored Folders" and you just add your folders there.

Comment: [Ignored Folders](https://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/ignored_folders_sure) only seems to be for PHP. Java doesn't have this feature as of 7.1 RC1.

Comment: I can confirm @PaulCalcraft's observation. The filter is also absent when the project type is HTML5 in NetBeans IDE 7.3 (PHP edition).

Comment: Works for Netbeans 8.2 with PHP projects but you have to restart Netbeans

Answer (score 8):

You can configure include/exclude file patterns on a project by project basis. This feature will allow you to add an exclude pattern for your 'tmp' directory, which will stop 'Go to File' suggesting files contained in this directory.

To configure bring up the project properties (File -> Project Properties), select sources, and click 'includes/excludes' button. I.e.:

[image: Netbeans Project Properties]

Comment: What version of Netbeans is this feature in.  I don't see it in 6.9.1

Comment: +1 Such a handy feature... Didn't even know it existed until your post. Thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to exclude folders for searching/scanning/refactoring, but still have them show in the IDE? I have a project which consists of different (but related) sites, and they have a common code folder. When I'm searching for common code, I often only want to make the changes in the common code folder for the site I'm on, and don't want to search through the others -- but do want to be able to get to those files if needed from the "Projects" or "Files" list. Is this sort of thing possible? Adding the folders to Project properties > Ignored Folders takes them out of the IDE completely...

Answer (score 3):

In my version of Netbeans (6.9.1 on Win 7), there is no button under Project Properties -> Source in which to enter exclusion patterns.

You have to go to Tools -> Options -> Miscellaneous -> Files and add the necessary file names or extensions under "files ignored by the IDE" in the Ignored Files Pattern field regexp.

For ignoring an entire folder, it is (in my version) on the project properties screen, but not under Sources; instead look at the "Ignored Folders" category.