# Exclude folders from search, but still consider in navigation for Netbeans 7 (php)

Tags: php, netbeans

I'm using Netbeans 7 for php. Is it possible to exclude folders from search ONLY, and do not exclude code of these folders from navigation, when I perform ctrl+click navigation on class/method/constant name?

In Zend Studio to do this, I should mark folders as "Derived" (Properties of directory). I still can ctrl+click on derived classes to go to necessary declaration.

When I ignore folders in Netbeans, I cannot access to their code base through ctrl+click navigation anymore.

Answer (score 18):

When searching the project (Windows: CTRL + SHIFT + F) there is a checkbox named `Use Ignore List` which is different from project ignored folders.

Click the `edit` link to define your file(s), folder(s) or pattern(s) to exclude.

Project ignored folders are automatically ignore during project search.

Comment: Configuring the Ignore List: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558213/how-do-you-make-netbeans-ignore-files-when-searching-for-files/6044297#answer-9231609