# How to make NetBeans to ignore all non-versioned files in searching and analyzing?

Tags: php, svn, netbeans

How to make NetBeans ignoring all non-versioned files in searching and analyzing? Maybe there is some plugin? 
Or is it possible to make NetBeans use include path with higher priority then project files?

Comment: As a workaround you can use `Files ignored by the IDE`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9231609/1023562